# How to pass type of a control as argument?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn programming in C#. I have a method that takes two arguments `(bool(true_or_false)` and `typeof(type_of_control)`. I'm stuck on passing the `typeOf` argument.

Here is my litle code:

```
    private void PassControlType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setControlVisibility(false,typeof(TextBox));
    }

    private void setControlVisibility(bool b,Type t)
    {
        foreach (Control a in grpControls.Controls)
        {
            if (a.GetType() == typeof(t))
            {
                a.Visible = b;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to set the visibility of any controls of same type.

Comment: @SohaibJundi, awesome! Problem solved.

Comment: Do you want **only** `TextBox` objects, or also objects of types that **inherit** from `TextBox`?

Answer (score 0):

no need for `typeof(t))` in the if statement, put `t` directly. `typeof(t)` would return the type `Type` instead of the type you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Sohaib is right, you're essentially comparing `typeof(t)` to the type of `Type`, which will not work.  You can either do

```
if(a.GetType() == t)
```

OR, use generics!

```
private void setControlVisibility<T>(bool b) where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control a in grpControls.Controls)
    {
        if (a.GetType() == typeof(T)) // checking type of generic parameter "T"
        {
            a.Visible = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Because we have constrained the generic parameter `T` to `Control`, this will work as `Visible` is defined on the `Control` class.  You' call it thusly:

```
private void PassControlType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setControlVisibility<TextBox>(false);
}
```